# how to run convert command of image magick

Tags: image-processing

I am executing the convert command of Image Magick with the syntax:

```
magick convert -units pixelsperinch image2.jpg -density 600 out.png
```

But not getting any results. How can we execute convert command without using magick.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, in English? Your first command creates a PNG file with specific dpi. Then you immediately overwrite that image with a new one with a blue background, so there is no point to running the first command.

Comment: I am not getting the results from any one the command mentioned above.

Comment: So if you delete the file `out.png` and then run the above command it doesn't create a new `out.png` and there is no error message. Is that correct?

Comment: It will create the new out.png file but same as orignal file without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value in the file, you need to use `-set`:

```
convert image2.jpg -set density 600 -set units pixelsperinch out.png
```

Now check what we got:

```
identify -verbose out.png | grep -Ei "units|resolution"
Resolution: 236.22x236.22
Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  png:pHYs: x_res=23622, y_res=23622, units=1
```

---

I am not sure I know a good way to explain when you need `-set` and when you don't. I'll try, and if anyone can improve it, I'll write up the improvements.

Let's look at an example, like `-size`. It is a *"setting"*, which means it just changes and remembers an internal setting or value until the end of the command or the value gets set differently, but it doesn't change any existing images. So, if I do:

```
convert -size 1024x768 ...
```

it sets the size and remembers it, and if I subsequently use `xc:blue` or similar, the canvas will get created with that size exactly as you would expect.

If, however, I do:

```
convert -size 1024x768 xc:blue ... -size 10x10 ...
```

the `-size 10x10` doesn't actually change the size of the already existing 1024x768 blue canvas, it just remembers that any canvases created in future should be 10x10.

So, `-density` and `-units` work like settings as above.

Now let's look at `-set`. That is an *"operator"*, as opposed to a *"setting"*. When you use an *"operator"*, it will apply that operation immediately to all images currently loaded - and potentially change all images currently loaded. So, `-resize` is another example of an *"operator"*. When you use it, it will immediately resize all loaded images.

So, if I do this:

```
convert image1.jpg image2.jpg -resize 800x600 image3.jpg ...
```

it will resize `image1.jpg` and `image2.jpg` immediately to 800x600 but leave `image3.jpg` unaffected.

---

Now the tutorial is over, you can hopefully see that you want to alter/change the loaded image, so you need to use an *"operator"* rather than a *"setting"*.